# Azure Cli permission denied error on Ubuntu

Tags: python, azure, ubuntu, apache2, azure-cli

I'm working on a project using Python(3) and Django in which I have implemented an application to run few `azure cli` commands, I have setup a virtual machine with `Ubuntu 18.04` and `apace2` and deployed my application on it.

Then I have install the `azure-cli` and using the it via the Python's subprocess module as:

```
def auth_group(grp_name):
    # cli().invoke(['login'])
    subprocess2.call(['sudo', 'az', 'login'])
    cli().invoke(['group', 'create', '--name', grp_name, '--location', 'centralus'])
```

But it returns an err when I check the apache's logs as:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.azure'
```

What can be the cause of this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a system assigned VM identity to allow your VM to make calls to ARM.

This quickstart shows you how to use a system-assigned identity for a Linux virtual machine (VM) to access the Azure Resource Manager API. Managed identities for Azure resources are automatically managed by Azure and enable you to authenticate to services that support Azure AD authentication without needing to insert credentials into your code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm